# Merging git repo's and suggested workflow

Tags: git, github, workflow, e-commerce

I am new to git and github. I have two servers, one for production and one for development each with a separate repo. Right now all of history is on the development server and our deployment to production consists of manually copying the files over.

What would be a recommended workflow for my environment? I was thinking I could make a develop branch on prod and check the branch out on dev, but all the history is on dev and I would like to keep it.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Add the develop repo as a remote on the production repo, and pull from develop when a release is ready and tested, perhaps?

Here's the classic article on Git workflows: http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/